# Beautifulsoup can't find an excel-download link for Anaconda Python 2.7

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download an excel file with Python automatically but I could not find the excel file's link tag with Beautifulsoup.

Here is my code snippet:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.sse.com.cn/market/othersdata/margin/detail/"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

soup.find_all("a", {"class": "download-export"})
```

Comment: are you sure "download-export" exists in the page itself?

Comment: this page use JavaScript to add elements. BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript. You may need `Selenium` to control web browser. Or use DevTool in Chrome/Firefox to see if JavaScript use different url to get those elements - I then you can read this url. Or maybe you will see url to excel file and you can generate it manually so you don't have to search it on page.

Comment: or maybe it sends different content when it thinks you are bot/script, not human. Maybe save html in file and open in browser to see what you get.

Comment: it seems this file alway has similar name - `rzrqjygk + data + .xls` - so you could download it without getting `"download-export"`